# background image in bootstrap/css does not cover full screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-vue

I am using a background-image on the main div of the component, but it is only covering the content that I provide in that main div (like if I just have half-page content it only renders behind it not on full screen). It covers all when I use position fixed but then scroll function is disabled.

```
.container-div {
  background: url("../assets/images/bucket.jpg");
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container-div {
  background: url("../assets/images/bucket.jpg");
  position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh; //Change this as per design needs
  width: 100%; //Change this as per design needs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using vh and vw instead of % for width and height

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

what it will do is that it will make the image cover 100% of viewport width and height.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) Gave you thumbs-up too but it does not show publically.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of the css you asked will depend on the size of the parent element. Please refer to the link below and example source code.

[korean developer blog](https://velog.io/@naynara/%EB%AA%A8%EB%8B%AC-%ED%8C%9D%EC%97%85%EB%9C%B0%EB%95%8C-%EB%B0%94%EB%8B%A5-%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A1%A4-%EB%A7%89%EA%B8%B0)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>모바일 스크롤 막기</title>
<style type="text/css">
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.cont {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 330px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cont1 { background-color: #F29B76; }
.cont2 { background-color: #EA68A2; }
.cont3 { background-color: #32B16C; }
.cont4 { background-color: #556FB5; } 
.nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
}
.nav .menu {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #EA68A2;
}
button { 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:100;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
.bnt_open { right:110px; }

/* 바디에 스크롤 막는 방법 */
.not_scroll{
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.not_scroll .cont {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="bnt_open">메뉴보기</button>
    <button type="button" class="bnt_close">메뉴닫기</button>
    <div style="display:none" class="nav">
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
        <a class="menu">menu1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont cont1">content1</div>
    <div class="cont cont2">content2</div>
    <div class="cont cont3">content3</div>
    <div class="cont cont4">content4</div>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        var posY;
        
        $(".bnt_open").on("click", function(e){
            posY = $(window).scrollTop();
            
            $("html, body").addClass("not_scroll");
            $(".nav").css("display","block");
            $(".cont").css("top",-posY);
        });
        
        $(".bnt_close").on("click", function(){
            $("html, body").removeClass("not_scroll");
            $(".nav").css("display","none");
            posY = $(window).scrollTop(posY);
        });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[example source code](https://jsfiddle.net/2kx2kmch/)

Answer (score 0):

It surely can be painful sometimes to set a full-screen background image, especially with BS. Try this method if you want to apply the background to the entire body-

```
  body {
   background: url('../assets/images/bucket.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;/*For Safari*/
  -moz-background-size: cover;/*For Mozilla*/
   background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;/*For Opera*/
 }
```

For applying the background for a div, the answer provided by @NigelDcruz is on point!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work for me. I got the answer though. The above answer works perfectly.

Comment: @flolegend I forgot we were adding a background to a div. Nigel's answer is perfect for it! My answer holds good for applying it to the entire body!